# Actionbar items are not shown when the background image is white

Tags: android, material-design, android-appbarlayout

I'm using `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout` with a background image to create the following effect:

[image]

However, when the background is white at the top, the action bar's controls are not visible to the human eye (or barely visible):

[image]

I like material design, but this seems a bit strange to me - having to scroll down in those cases so that the AppBar would pin at the top in order to see the actions.

A lot of apps use this design, so I guess people are ok with it? Should I just *let it be*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page on [Imagery](https://material.io/guidelines/style/imagery.html#imagery-ui-integration) has a section on "Text protection". Quoting from there:

> To make typography legible on top of imagery, apply text protection in
>   the form of scrims. Scrims are lightweight, translucent material
>   layers.

So if you want to ensure the text is legible you add a *scrim* to your `Toolbar`, e.g. (if it's not possible to edit the images) a `View` with a background made of a shape drawable with a color gradient.

Comment: Thanks, using a drawable with gradient in front of my image solved the problem!